# How to add a picture onto an existing pdf file?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a scanned pdf file which is [an application form](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1tqjgoFeXuKOBvXDncBGa3ozY8Nbe_2AXZ5Go3SKatOP47iCyzhm-A5OTR9PP/edit?pli=1), and a picture which is the scanned version of one's signature (for example, [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Autograph_of_Benjamin_Franklin.svg/200px-Autograph_of_Benjamin_Franklin.svg.png)) and can be in any image format such as eps or png. I would like to put the signature picture on the blank space right to "APPLICANT:" on the second page of the application form. I wonder how to do that in TeX?

I have tried the following non-TeX methods, but none succeeded.

1. The first way is using gimp. I first import the application form
   into gimp, and then paste the signature picture on the space right
   to "APPLICANT:" on the second page of the application form.

   But the
   problems are that:

   - It seems that I can only import one page of the
     application form into gimp, not all of the two pages.
   - Also when I
     save the modification, the closest format to pdf I can save to is
     ps, and the resolution has been downgraded and the storage size of
     the saved file is 10 times bigger than the original application form and the signature picture.
2. The second way is using Libreoffice Draw. I have installed  the
   libreoffice-pdfimport package. But after I import the application
   form into Libreoffice Draw,

   - all the scanned content is not imported,
     and
   - the layout is different from the layout of the original
     application form.

So can TeX help? Can it lay the signature picture directly on the application form pdf file,

- without having to convert between formats,
- without having to create much bigger files while keeping the original resolution,
- without having to split and combine pages of a multi-page pdf file,
- without having to rasterize other parts of the pdf file, i.e. without losing the text I later added to the application form pdf file by having to convert the whole pdf into images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This can be done with pdflatex easily. You can e.g. use `graphicx` or `pdfpages` to import the pdf and a picture-environment to overlay it with some text. Here e.g. an example with `eso-pic`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[page=1]{test}}
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{8cm},\LenToUnit{10cm}){\Huge\bfseries TEXT}}}%

\begin{document}
\mbox{} % to create a page

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Like Ulrike Fischer wrote, you could use `graphicx` or `pdfpages` for inserting your PDF into the document.

An alternative to `eso-pic` is the package [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) which you can use to create overlays. For example something along:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [xshift=150mm,yshift=-80mm]
    at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics{signature}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: For me, this produces an error: "File ended while scanning use of \g@addto@macro". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Zubo, this [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/e45a393e3ed8274fc5a8fc8faaef3d2f) works for me. I've had to add the `remember picture` option, though (I'll update my answer). Without it the signature just isn't displayed - still, I don't see your error. I am using texlive 2014 on Fedora 23. I don't remember (!) if the `remember picture` option wasn't strictly necessary 4 years ago, with the texlive version I was using then - or if this was an oversight while copy and pasting.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly! You're probably right, likely some copypasting oversight, maybe on my part. Meanwhile, I've used this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331818/superimpose-a-pdf-page-and-a-pdf-vector-image?noredirect=1#comment813392_331818

Answer (score 5):

### Case 1: Overlaying an image on a single-page PDF file

1. User defined data:

   ```
   \def\BackImage{example-image-a4.pdf}
   \def\FrontImage{example-image-a.pdf}

   \def\ScaleBack{1}
   \def\ScaleFront{0.5}

   \def\Columns{10}
   \def\Rows{10}
   ```
2. Navigation grid:

   [image]
3. Final result:

   [image]
4. Minimal Working Example:

   Please TeX it with `xelatex`. Set `border` to `0` to remove the padding.

   ```
   \documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pstricks}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   % User defined data:
   \def\BackImage{example-image-a4.pdf}
   \def\FrontImage{example-image-a.pdf}

   \def\ScaleBack{1}
   \def\ScaleFront{0.5}

   \def\Columns{10}
   \def\Rows{10}

   % Internal used data:
   \newsavebox\IBack
   \savebox\IBack{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleBack]{\BackImage}}

   \newsavebox\IFront
   \savebox\IFront{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleFront]{\FrontImage}}


   \psset
   {
       xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBack/\Columns\relax,
       yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBack/\Rows\relax,
   }


   \begin{document}


   \begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
       \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
       \psgrid
   \end{pspicture}


   \begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
       \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
       \rput(5,1){\usebox\IFront}
   \end{pspicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

### Case 2: Overlaying an image on each page of a PDF file

```
% Set border=0 if you have found  the coordinate 
% at which you place the front image on the back image.
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% User defined data:
\def\BackImage{mwe.pdf}
\def\FrontImage{example-image-a.pdf}

\def\ScaleBack{1}
\def\ScaleFront{0.5}

\def\Columns{10}
\def\Rows{10}

% Internal used data:
\newsavebox\IBack
\savebox\IBack{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleBack,page=2]{\BackImage}}

\newsavebox\IFront
\savebox\IFront{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleFront]{\FrontImage}}


\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBack/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBack/\Rows\relax,
}


\begin{document}

% Comment out the following code
% to locate the coordinate to overlay the front image on the back image.
%\begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
%   \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
%   \psgrid
%\end{pspicture}


\newcount\x
\IfFileExists{\BackImage}{%
    \loop
            \ifnum\x<\XeTeXpdfpagecount"\BackImage"\relax
            \advance\x by 1\relax
            \savebox\IBack{\includegraphics[page=\the\x,scale=\ScaleBack]{\BackImage}}%
            \begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
                        \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
                        \rput(0.5\wd\IBack,0.85\ht\IBack){\usebox\IFront}
            \end{pspicture}         
    \repeat
}{%
    \noindent\hfill NOTHING! \hfill\null
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. But in LaTeX we have `\newcommand`. Please use it instead of `\def`.

Answer (score 5):

As Ulrike already suggested `pdfpages` is a good option. It offers a `picturecommand` option which can help you to place something over the included page. Here you have the code I used with your files:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1}]{2012Application}
\newpage
\includepdf[pages={2},%
    picturecommand={\setlength\unitlength{1cm}%
         \put(6,11){\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{signature}}}]%
   {2012Application}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notes:

1. Using ImageMagick, convert the signature file from PNG to PDF.
2. Using ImageMagick, convert the application file from PDF to PDF to remove non-standard features. Xe(La)TeX does not like the non-standard features in the original application.
3. For the first TeXing, use the navigation grid to find the location at which you want to put the signature.
4. In the second TeXing, disable the first `pspicture` (which contains grid) and make sure you change `border` to `0bp` to get a tight output without border.
5. Use XeLaTeX for TeXing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% User defined data:
\def\BackImage{Application.pdf}
\def\FrontImage{Signature.pdf}

\def\ScaleBack{1}
\def\ScaleFront{0.4}

\def\Columns{10}
\def\Rows{10}

% Internal used data:
\newsavebox\IBack
\savebox\IBack{\includegraphics[page=2,scale=\ScaleBack]{\BackImage}}

\newsavebox\IFront
\savebox\IFront{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleFront]{\FrontImage}}


\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBack/\Columns\relax,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBack/\Rows\relax,
}


\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
    \psgrid
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(\Columns,\Rows)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBack}
    \rput(3.5,4.2){\usebox\IFront}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```